# Generate new url depended on input text

Tags: javascript

I need to make new URL depending on input text

```
Name: <input type="text" id="myText" >
<button onclick="myFunction()">check tracking</button>
```

And DHL making it adding code to URL for example:
`https://nolp.dhl.de/nextt-online-public/en/search?piececode=`

plus tracking code here. The demo URL is this: 
`https://nolp.dhl.de/nextt-online-public/en/search?piececode=48484848484848484`

Here is Javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
var inputed_code = document.getElementById("myText").value ;
var dhlurl = "https://nolp.dhl.de/nextt-online-public/en/search?piececode="
var new_url = dhlurl + inputed_code ;
    window.open(new_url, "_blank");
}
```

Why doesn't this code result in a new URL?

Comment: Have you confirmed that `myFunction` is being called properly? Perhaps by adding a log statement?

Comment: You should write some `console.log();` in order to target the real problem. Is your function executed when clicking on the button ? Have you some js errors in the console ? Have you tried to log the new URL ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function generateUrl() {
  var dhlurl = "https://nolp.dhl.de/nextt-online-public/en/search?piececode=";
  var inputed_code = document.getElementById("myText").value;
  var new_url = dhlurl + inputed_code;
  console.log(new_url);

  //window.open wont work from the SO code snippet, but you can see url is created by looking at the console.log()
  //window.open(new_url, "_blank");
}
```

```html
Name: <input type="text" id="myText">
<button onclick="generateUrl()">check tracking</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your javascript function into script tags on the bottom of your body like this

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var inputed_code = document.getElementById("myText").value ;
var dhlurl = "https://nolp.dhl.de/nextt-online-public/en/search?piececode="
var new_url = dhlurl + inputed_code ;
    window.open(new_url, "_blank");
}
</script>
```

And it will work.